# How can I transform this FFT into real FFT ($\tt rfft$)?

Tags: fft, python

I'm using Python [`numpy.fft.rfft`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.rfft.html) (real FFT) that produces an output of length `n / 2 + 1`. It works. Now I'm rewriting my algorithm in C++, using [this rosettacode.org FFT implementation](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform#C.2B.2B) below.

How to turn it into a *real FFT* algorithm (i.e. input of length `n`, output of length `n/2 +1`) ?

```
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>
#include <valarray>

const double PI = 3.141592653589793238460;

typedef std::complex<double> Complex;
typedef std::valarray<Complex> CArray;

void fft(CArray& x)
{
    const size_t N = x.size();
    if (N <= 1) return;
    CArray even = x[std::slice(0, N/2, 2)];
    CArray  odd = x[std::slice(1, N/2, 2)];
    fft(even);
    fft(odd);
    for (size_t k = 0; k < N/2; ++k)
    {
        Complex t = std::polar(1.0, -2 * PI * k / N) * odd[k];
        x[k    ] = even[k] + t;
        x[k+N/2] = even[k] - t;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to only use the first `n/2+1` elements from the final output.
BTW, do you know that FFTW also has a [real-FFT implementation](http://www.fftw.org/doc/One_002dDimensional-DFTs-of-Real-Data.html)?